# Size of the app to big after implements better voice sip-js cordova plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, sip

I am working with Ionic to make an application that works with sip calls.

I am using this cordova plugin:

https://github.com/BetterVoice/iOS-SIP.js

It uses an webrtc library to make it works. The problem is that after I added it to my project the size of my app increased from 12 mb to more than 300 mbs.

I was wondering if there is a way to reduce that huge size

Comment: webrtc library is 600MB